# Conservative extensions and elementary equivalence- anything in common?

Tags: logic

What is the difference between a Conservative extension, T', of a theory T, and a theory that is elementarily equivalent to T (but non-isomorphic, having, say, more elements). As far as I gathered, T' is a conservative extension of T if T'∩ L = T (i.e. all theorems of T' in the language L are already theorems of T). Isn't this the case with two elementarily equivalent theories T and T'?

Comment: Two $\mathcal L$-structures are *elementary equivalent*; "by definition" they "share" the same language $\mathcal L$. In the case of $T'$ being a *conservative extension* of $T$, the language of $T$ is a subset of the language of $T'$.

Comment: Two $\mathcal L$-structures are *elementary equivalent* when they satisfy the same sentences. If $T'$ is a conservative extension of $T$, then a structure satisfying $T' \cap \mathcal L$ will satisfy also $T$, but we can have a theorem of $T'$ using e.g. a constant of the expanded language (i.e. not belonging to the language $\mathcal L$ in common with $T$) and this theorem will not necessarily be satisfied by an $\mathcal L$-structure for $T$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks

Comment: Elementary equivalence is a property of structures, not of theories.  So the last part of your first sentence, "a theory that is elementarily equivalent to T", is meaningless.  So is the last sentence of the question.